# Diferencia entra returnValue y callFake Jasmine

Tags: karma-jasmine

Tengo una duda acerca de cual es mejor utilización para returnValue and callFake. Se que pueden utilizarse las dos y serian correcta. Pero.. ¿Cual de las dos formas es mas recomendable utilizar?

```
spyOn(window, "open").and.callFake((params) => null);
spyOn(window, "open").and.returnValue(null);
```